# How Can I use struct in yacc file to implement parser

Tags: c, parsing, struct, yacc, anonymous

I am trying to implement parser with lexer and I need to use struct in yacc file.
definition and usage of struct in the yacc file is below

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void yyerror(const char *s);
extern int yylex();
%}

%token KW_AND KW_OR KW_NOT KW_EQUAL KW_LESS KW_NIL KW_LIST
%token KW_APPEND KW_CONCAT KW_SET KW_DEF KW_FOR KW_IF KW_EXIT
%token KW_LOAD KW_DISP KW_TRUE KW_FALSE OP_PLUS OP_MINUS OP_DIV
%token OP_MULT OP_OP OP_CP OP_COM IDENTIFIER

%left OP_PLUS OP_MINUS
%left OP_MULT OP_DIV

%union {
    struct {
        int intval;
        char frac[10];
    }num;
    
}

%token <num> VALUEF
%type <num> exp
%type <num> IDENTIFIER 

%%

start
  : exp { printf("Result: %d%s\n", $1.num.intval, $1.num.frac); }
  | function_def { printf("#function\n"); }
  | OP_OP KW_EXIT OP_CP { printf("(exit)\n"); exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }
  ;
 //rest of  the code
```

but when I run this yacc file like below

```
bison -d gpp_interpreter.y
flex gpp_lexer.l
gcc lex.yy.c gpp_interpreter.tab.c -o parser
```

I take error like this:

```
gpp_interpreter.y: In function ‘yyparse’:
gpp_interpreter.y:32:40: error: ‘struct <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘num’
   32 |   : exp { printf("Result: %d%s\n", $1.num.intval, $1.num.frac); }
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: The errors like ‘struct Number’ has no member named ‘num’ are due to incorrect access to the members of struct Number. It seems you are trying to access num as if it's a member of struct Number, but actually, num is a variable of type struct Number.

To fix this, you should directly access the members of struct Number (intval and frac) instead of using num.intval or num.frac.(Answer of Chatgpt-4 ,it soved my error)